# When comparing 2 strings when the user inputs the first and the second being an F string having integers how to have the integers being whatever?

Tags: python-3.x

```
command = input()
num1 = int()
num2 = int()
if command == f'Cut {num1} {num2}':
    print('Success!')
```

I thought maybe this will work, but it doesn't and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Do you want the user to type `num1` and `num2` or the `num1` and `num2` to take the integers typed in `command`?

Comment: To take the integers typed in the command

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Try with this: `num1 = int(command.split()[1])`
and `num2 = int(command.split()[2])`